# Is it NP-hard to find the min set of nodes in a graph so that the set of paths joining them cover all the nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np

Given a directed graph $G=(V,A)$ and given for every pair of nodes $(i,j)$
a valid path $P(i,j)=(v_1=i,...,v_l=j)$ on $G$.
Find a minimum set of nodes $M$ such that $\bigcup_{(i,j)\in M\times M}P(i,j)=V$ (i.e. all the nodes are covered by at least one path between the selected nodes).

I have attempted to reduce the minimum set-cover problem but without success so far.

The even more general problem can be defined in terms of a given function $P:V\times V \rightarrow 2^V$. Find a minimum cardinality set $M\subseteq V$ such that $\forall i \in V, \exists (a,b) \in M \times M: i \in P(a,b)$.

Comment: Is the intersection sign supposed to be the union sign? Also, NP-complete problems are Yes/No questions. Your question here is perhaps "Is there a set of M paths which covers all vertices?"

Comment: It sounds as if it would be fairly easy to reduce to 3-SAT but I need to think a bit about it.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be union, sorry, I fix this

Comment: I would be more interested that you reduce 3-SAT to this problem (than the opposite ;-)). For the NP-Complete problem (assuming it is), you can say: find a set M of at most k nodes.

Comment: The graph seems superfluous. As I understand the problem statement we don't really care about the connectivity at all: we can state it in terms of a function $P: V\times V \to 2^V$ subject to the constraint $\{u,v\}\subseteq P(u,v)$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the problem you propose is even more general. I’ve edited the problem including this new formulation

Comment: @user3020699 It’s not more general, it’s exactly the same problem, just stated in a simpler way.

Comment: OK, I can show that we can reduce 3-sat to this problem, but I have teaching now. Will write up later.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think it is more general since the output of the function P don't need to correspond to paths in a graph (it is a stronger constraint to define P functions as paths). How would you transform the "more general problem" to the initial problem on graphs (what edges would you use) ?

Comment: All right, I didn’t check what you actually wrote in the question, which indeed does not include a requirement that the $P(i,j)$ form a path. I assumed from the comments that we are talking about reformulation of the original problem solely in terms of the paths $P(i,j)$ as subsets of $V$ without reference to the ambient graph $(V,E)$, which is irrelevant to the problem (you can always take it to be the complete graph).

Comment: In fact, "Why don't we just assume that it's a complete graph?" was a step in the thought process which led to my comment.

Comment: Since it is a digraph, we can take the ambient digraph to be the digraph with $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$ as arcs for each pair of vertices $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Ah, the subtlety is that the "more general" problem you've added to the question isn't the restatement of my comment because it removes the constraint that $\{u,v\}\subseteq P(u,v)$.

Comment: What is wrong with the following idea? Let $V'$ be the graph obtained from $V$ by collapsing each strong connected component to a point. Two vertices $a,b$ are in the same strong connected component, if there is a path from a to b and vice versa. Then a minimal set is given by an arbitrary choice of representatives of the sources and sinks of $V'$. This equivalence relation can be computed even in $O(n)$ time with Tarjans algorithm.

Comment: I dont think that the graph is irrelevant. For example, if $P$ comes from a Graph, then it has for example the additional property that $w\in P(u,v)$ implies that $P(u,w)\cup P(w,v)\subset P(u,v)$.

Comment: Ah I see $P(u,v)$ is not the set of all vertices on some path between $u,v$, but only the vertices on some chosen valid path.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed NP-hard, and cannot even be well-approximated in polynomial time.  To see this, consider an instance $(\mathcal{F}, V)$ of the set cover problem.  We construct an instance of the monitor cover problem as follows.  The vertex set is $\mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2 \cup V$, where $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ are two copies of $\mathcal{F}$.  If $a,b \in \mathcal{F}_1$ let $P(a,b)=\mathcal{F}_1$.  Similarly, if $a,b \in \mathcal{F}_2$, let $P(a,b)=\mathcal{F}_2$.  If $a \in \mathcal{F}_1$ and $b \in \mathcal{F}_2$ and $a$ and $b$ correspond to the same set of $\mathcal{F}$, let $P(a,b)=\{a,b\} \cup X$, where $X \subseteq V$ is the set of vertices in $a$.  For all other pairs of vertices $a,b$, let $P(a,b)=\{a,b\}$.  Let $M \subseteq \mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2 \cup V$ be an optimal solution to this monitor cover instance.  Let $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ be an optimal solution to the set cover instance.  Observe that $\mathcal{S}_1 \cup \mathcal{S}_2$ is a feasible solution to the monitor cover instance, where $\mathcal{S}_1$ and  $\mathcal{S}_2$ are the copies of $\mathcal{S}$ in $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$.  On the other hand, it is easy to check that $|M| \geq |\mathcal{S}|$.  Thus, if we can solve monitor cover in polynomial time, we would get a $2$-approximation algorithm for set cover.  However, it is well-known that for every $\epsilon > 0$, set cover does not admit a $(1-\epsilon) \log n$-approximation algorithm, where $n$ is the size of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the reduction from 3-SAT;
We are given boolean satisfiability problem of the form
$$
(a_1 \vee b_1 \vee c_1) \wedge \dotsb \wedge (a_k \vee b_k \vee c_k),
$$
where each of the $a_i,b_i,c_j \in \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n,\bar{x}_1,\dotsc,\bar{x}_n\}$  (so there are $n$ variables).

Let $N$ be an integer to be determined later.
Here is the graph we are constructing. First, the vertex set:

- Two vertices, $x_i$, $\bar{x}_i$.
- One 'terminal' vertex $T$.
- One vertex, $C_i$ for each clause in the boolean expression.
- Vertices $v_{i,1},\dotsc,v_{i,N}$ for each $i=1,\dotsc,n$.

We describe the edges as a union of paths:
These are the designated paths for the pairs $(x_i,T)$
and $(\bar{x}_i,T)$.

From $x_i$ (and $\bar{x}_i)$ there is the path
starting as $x_i,v_{i,1},\dotsc,v_{i,N}$,
then passing through all vertices corresponding to clauses containing
the variable $x_i$ (in some order), and finally ending at $T$.

All other paths from some vertex to another is simply an edge between them.

Now, an assignment making the formula true, corresponds to choosing $n$
paths, (picking if $x_i$ or $\bar{x}_i$ is true) each passing through the sequence of auxiliary vertices
$v_{i,1},\dotsc,v_{i,N}$. This covers all vertices, except
$n$ vertices $x_i$ or $\bar{x}_i$, for which we need to cover, say via
the direct edge to $T$. Hence, $2n$ paths in total.

Now, if we DO NOT choose any of the long paths
$x_i \to T$ or $\bar{x}_i \to T$,
we need to cover $x_i,v_{i,1},\dotsc,v_{i,N}$ by some other means,
but this requires at least $N/2$ extra paths.
So, if $N$ is large, this is worse than $2n$.

Hence, we can path-cover the above graph with $2n$ paths,
if and only if the formula is satisfiable.

Comment: But the problem in the question isn't covering with the fewest number of paths, but finding the fewest number of endpoints. The $M$ of your assignment looks like $\{T, x_1, \ldots, x_n, \bar{x}_1, \ldots, \bar{x}_n\}$.

Comment: I think it can be fixed by making the path $x_i \to T$ include $\bar{x}_i$ and similarly the path $\bar{x}_i \to T$ include $x_i$. Then we need at least $n+1$ endpoints in $M$: $T$ is only included in paths which contain it as an endpoint, so $T \in M$; $x_i$ is only included in paths which contain either it or $\bar{x}_i$ as an endpoint, so we need at least one of them to be in $M$. But if both $x_i$ and $\bar{x}_i$ are in $M$ we still need $n$ other elements in $M$ by the same argument, so $|M| > n+1$. I think this even avoids the need for auxiliaries unless there's only one clause.

Comment: Ah, @PeterTaylor yes you are right, your adjustment seems to work, and in fact makes the problem/construction simpler.